# Vue js after routing nested array not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating a single page Application using Vue and Vue Router, the issue I'm running into, is that once I click through the first level of the routing, I can't seem to loop through the nested data.

Clicking the category routes to the category page as expected, but nothing in the projects v-for loop seems to show up, and I've got no errors in the console to go off of, so I'm kind of spinning my wheels at this point.  Any help would be insanely appreciated.

```js
//Router
const projectCategoryPage = {
  props: ['projectCategory', 'id'],
  template: `
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'Home'}">{{id}}</router-link>
                </h2>
                <div class="projectsWrapper">
                    <project-comp v-for="project in id.projects" v-bind:project="project"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  `
}

const projectSpecificPage = {
  props: ['project', 'id'],
  template: `
      <div class="container">
          {{id}}
      </div>
  `
}

const homePage = {
  props: ['projectCategories'],
  template: `
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div v-for="projectCategory in projectCategories">
                <h2>
                    <router-link :to="{name: 'project', params: {id: projectCategory.category}}">{{projectCategory.category}}</router-link>
                </h2>
                <div class="projectsWrapper">
                    <project-comp v-for="project in projectCategory.projects.slice(0,3)" v-bind:project="project"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
}


const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: homePage
  },
  {
    path: '/project/:id',
    name: 'project',
    component: projectCategoryPage,
    props: true,

  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

// Individual Components
Vue.component('project-comp', {
  props: ['project'],
  filters: {

  },
  methods: {

  },
  template: `
    <div class="projectItem">
        <div class="imgWrapper">
            <img src="{{project.img}}" />
        </div>
        {{project.name}}
    </div>
  `
});


//App

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {
    projectCategories: [{
        category: 'category1',
        projects: [{
          name: 'Project 1',
          img: 'images/img1.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 2',
          img: 'images/img2.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 3',
          img: 'images/img3.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 4',
          img: 'images/img4.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 5',
          img: 'images/img5.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 6',
          img: 'images/img6.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 7',
          img: 'images/img7.jpg'
        }]
      },
      {
        category: 'category2',
        projects: [{
          name: 'Project 1 cat2',
          img: 'images/img1.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 2',
          img: 'images/img2.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 3',
          img: 'images/img3.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 4',
          img: 'images/img4.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 5',
          img: 'images/img5.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 6',
          img: 'images/img6.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 7',
          img: 'images/img7.jpg'
        }]
      },
      {
        category: 'category3',
        projects: [{
          name: 'Project 1',
          img: 'images/img1.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 2',
          img: 'images/img2.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 3',
          img: 'images/img3.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 4',
          img: 'images/img4.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 5',
          img: 'images/img5.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 6',
          img: 'images/img6.jpg'
        }, {
          name: 'Project 7',
          img: 'images/img7.jpg'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  template: `
      <router-view v-bind:projectCategories="projectCategories"/>
  `
})
```

Comment: Using `v-for`, especially on components, requires you to bind a `key` property. See  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Also, `<router-view>` does not have / use a `projectCategories` prop

Comment: I think you should get the vue-router params by this way: `<div>{{ $route.params.id }}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

> [Vue Router - Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.

To react to params changes in the same component, you can simply watch the $route object:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

Or, use the beforeRouteUpdate navigation guard introduced in 2.2:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
    // don't forget to call next()
  }
}
```